# Confusion about the calculation of getting full house and two pairs

Tags: permutations, combinations

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

-By your "two pair method" applied to a full house you don't distinguish the above two hands so you undercount.

-So every two pair will be counted twice, so you need to divide by two

Can anyone explain this problem more explicitly for me ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Would you please link to the answer you are referencing instead of the MSE "ask a new question" site?

Comment: Why would every two pair be counted twice? I dont understand this

Comment: Would you please actually read my comment and provide the requested link. That would be far more useful than just repeating part of your post without addressing the fact that your post as is makes no sense, not providing at all anything that would explain what you are talking about, but instead including a link that *has nothing to do with your question*.